# How to display date in UltraWinGrid SummaryRow in MM-dd-yyyy?

Tags: c#-4.0, ultrawingrid

I am using UltraWinGrid and displaying the sum of the values using the SummaryRow. I need to display the maximum date in the summary row in MM-dd-yyyy format. Only date should be there. How to achieve this. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer form the site 
http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

```
SummarySettings SumSummary = new SummarySettings();

e.Layout.Bands[0].Columns["DateColumn"].AllowRowSummaries = AllowRowSummaries.False;

SumSummary = e.Layout.Bands[0].Summaries.Add(SummaryType.Minimum, e.Layout.Bands[0].Columns["DateColumn"]);

SumSummary.DisplayFormat = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}";
```